# Find the path that most closely resembles all other paths of a group of 3D paths

Tags: r, dtw

I am attempting to write an algorithm for finding a 3D path most closely resembles all other paths in a group of 3D paths. If you would look at the graph in the (at the bottom) provided link it should output trace1. (by eyeballing it)

To be able to make a comparison of resemblance for the paths I have calculated the path cost of the paths for every axis using Dynamic Time Warping(DTW) with every other path in the group giving me the following dataframe:

```
   from to         x         y         z
1     1  2 2.2460834 2.3350118 0.9898763
2     1  3 4.0703514 3.2873548 1.7424783
3     1  4 3.1386396 3.1925206 2.7434982
4     1  5 2.3475482 3.4232058 1.3965482
5     1  6 2.2899544 2.0498909 1.2892379
6     1  7 2.9042872 2.6445606 0.7676169
7     1  8 1.5259118 1.5580012 1.1033320
8     1  9 2.1399503 1.6253582 0.8797432
9     1 10 4.0400429 1.8293614 2.0989448
10    2  1 2.2460834 2.3350118 0.9898763
11    2  3 1.4793632 1.0747873 1.2075596
12    2  4 1.1333285 1.5574448 1.7058433
13    2  5 0.7593649 1.1794035 1.0677958
14    2  6 0.6467899 0.4950420 0.8100349
15    2  7 0.7879115 0.6047349 1.0033941
...
90   10  9 1.929852 0.4064518 1.669125
```

From this dataframe I need the path which has the lowest values for most of the paths.

It's probably a fairly easy solution but after all the 3D translation and rotational mathematics the solution eludes me.

[Link to the graph & data I am processing](https://plot.ly/~Praevalens/2/) <- You can just click on the cross to close the registration window

Comment: @chinsoon12 No, I calculate the DTW cost of every axis of every path. The DTW cost signifies how much the paths differ from each other without the constraint of time. [See this image](https://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0169743916303732-gr2.jpg)

Comment: "the lowest values for most of the paths" .. it is not clear ... you have to choose a precise measure .. for exemple, for each path, the sum of the costs to all others paths (and in all direction) .. then you can order and choose the least. But lots of other measures could be use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem by summing up the individual costs of the axis DTW analyses, ranking those scores against the other scores from the same path origin, then summing up the rankings for every path group. The measurement with the lowest accumulative ranking is closest to every other path.

Conclusion: trace1 is most generic path with 5 and 6 on shared 2nd spot.

Code:

```
#add accumulative score
classification <- classification %>% mutate(score = classification$x + classification$y + classification$z)    

#rank by accumulative score, add ranking to the dataframe
classification$ranking <- vector(length = nrow(classification))
for (i in unique(classification$from)) {
  classificationGroup <- classification[classification$from == i,]
  classificationGroup <- classificationGroup[order(classificationGroup$score),]

  for (ii in 1:nrow(classificationGroup)){
    classification[classification$to == classificationGroup[ii,]$to & classification$from == classificationGroup[ii,]$from,]$ranking <- ii
  }
}    

combinedrankingdf <- data.frame(measurement = vector(length = length(unique(classification$to))), accumulativeRank = vector(length = length(unique(classification$to))))
for (i in 1:nrow(combinedrankingdf)){
  combinedrankingdf$measurement[i] <- i
  combinedrankingdf$accumulativeRank[i] <- sum(classification[classification$to == i,]$ranking)
}
```

*Note: "classification" is the dataframe portrayed in the question.*

Resulting output:

```
   measurement accumulativeRank
2            2               25
6            6               26
7            7               26
9            9               35
8            8               37
5            5               43
3            3               57
10          10               59
4            4               66
1            1               76
```